# Keras implement a Data Generator that outputs sample_weight

Tags: python, keras

I'm using a data generator to feed the `fit_generator`. My generator have as output the tuple `(x_val, y_val, val_sample_weights)` so showing sample weights. This is like:

```
import numpy as np
import keras
import librosa
from time import time
import random
from config import *

class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):

    'Generates data for Keras'

    def __init__(self, dataframe, batch_size=None, dim=None, labels_dim=None,
                 n_classes=None, shuffle=True, samples=None, duration=None, sample_weights=None):
        'Initialization'
        self.dim = dim
        self.batch_size = batch_size

        self.dataframe = dataframe
        self.dataframe = self.dataframe.sample(n=len(self.dataframe))
        self.samples = samples
        self.on_epoch_end()
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.sample_weights = sample_weights

    def __len__(self):
        'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
        return int(np.floor(len(self.dataframe) / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        'Generate one batch of data'
        random_pd = self.dataframe.iloc[self.batch_size*index : (index+1)*self.batch_size]
        # Generate data
        X, y = self.__data_generation(random_pd)
        return X, y
    def __data_generation(self, random_pd):
        'Generates data containing batch_size samples' # X : (n_samples, *dim, n_channels)
        # Initialization
        X = np.empty((self.batch_size, 1, self.samples))
        y = np.empty((self.batch_size, self.n_classes))
        i = 0
        while i < self.batch_size:
            for index, row in random_pd.iterrows():
                 # generate 
                y[i,] = label
                X[i,] = ...
                i += 1
        return X, y, self.sample_weights
```

so it will return `X, y, self.sample_weights`.

The problem is that we will get a `StopIteration: too many values to unpack` as it would expect 2 but I'm giving 3 values - as actually I'm doing.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "train.py", line 438, in <module>
train()
File "train.py", line 422, in train
callbacks=callbacks
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 1315, in fit_generator
initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2250, in fit_generator
max_queue_size=max_queue_size)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2383, in evaluate_generator
generator_output = next(output_generator)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py", line 584, in get
six.raise_from(StopIteration(e), e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/six.py", line 737, in raise_from
raise value
StopIteration: too many values to unpack
```

I call the fit_generator as usual passing my `training_generator` then

```
history = model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,
                                class_weight=class_weights,
                                verbose=1,
                                use_multiprocessing=True,
                                workers=24, 
                                steps_per_epoch=training_steps_per_epoch,
                                epochs=epochs,
                                validation_data=validation_generator,
                                validation_steps = validation_steps_per_epoch,
                                callbacks=callbacks
                                )
```

I do this because when using the `fit_generator` it is not possibile to pass the `sample_weight`, since the method signature only supports the `class_weight` - see here https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11800

Comment: You should pass the sample weights as batches, exactly like x and y.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean. Shall I split in batches the sample_weights or calculate on the fly for each batch within the data generation?

Comment: Do exactly the same as you did with X and Y. Make batches, don't pass the entire thing.

Comment: Ok right, at this point I think I have confused `sample_weight` and `class_weight`. I want the first one, so that the weights will be applied to the loss. Basically I should do like `sample_weights = class_weight.compute_sample_weight('balanced', y)` in the generator from `sklearn.utils`...

Comment: @DanielMöller using the batch like `sample_weights = class_weight.compute_sample_weight('balanced', y_batch)` is still giving me the error `too many values to unpack`. I have tried this as well - https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/31129/sample-importance-training-weights-in-keras

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh.... look at your return statements...

`__data_generation` returns 3 things. But you're doing `X, y = self.__data_generation(random_pd)`

Trying to get three values `(X,y,weights)` into two vars `(X,y)`.

Notice that `__get_item__` is also not returning the weights.

Comment: Ah so! We are closer now! Now point is, if I do `X, y, sample_weight = self.__data_generation(random_pd)`, why I get a `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have shape (4,) but got array with shape (1,) ` (I have 4 classes).

Comment: I think that is something for another question where you post your model and `y.shape` as it gets out of the generator.